# Taking Screen Shot When App is in Landscape Mode

Tags: ios, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation

I am working on an app which will only be in landscape. In that app I have a functionality that is take screenshot of that particular screen. I have implemented this code

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.window.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();;
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageView.image, nil, nil, nil);
```

Using this code I get screen shot of my app in portrait mode. I want it in landscape mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't add that `window`. If you add it your context size is wrong.

```
// Just use self.view.bounds.size is OK
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps late, but wrapping it in an UIImageView doesn't actually rotate the image itself.
Here's some code I wrote that creates a rotated image from the full window of your application.

```
UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

CGRect rect = [keyWindow bounds];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[keyWindow.layer renderInContext:context];

UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:[image CGImage] scale:1 orientation:UIImageOrientationLeft];
```

If you want it rotated right, just replace UIImageOrientationLeft with UIImageOrientationRight